# Import export data only for TB's data SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, import, export

I have a production database of 20 TB data. We migrated our database from Oracle to SQL Server. Our old application was based on a Cobol based platform. After migrating to SQL Server indexes are giving good results.

I am creating a schema with new set of indexes without any data. Now I want to migrate only the data.

Import/Export utility will take load log time and will fill up the log files also. Is there any other alternative of this ?

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be:

- Set the recovery model to simple.  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/recovery-models-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).
- Remove the indexes.
- Batch insert the rows or use `select into` (this minimizes logging).
- Re-create the indexes.

I admit that I haven't had to do this sort of thing in a long time in SQL Server.  There may be other methods that are faster -- such as backing up a table space/partition and restoring it in another location.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `bcp` utility to import/export data. For full details see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017